# Replacing words in a string, ignoring quotation marks

Tags: python, regex, string, file-io

I am examining a string of text, and I am looking to change certain words in the text, ignoring anything inside quotation marks.

Example:  If I wanted to replace "my" with "MY"

```
Hello my name is "Tom, and my favourite sport is football"
```

Would become

```
Hello MY name is "Tom, and my favourite sport is football"
```

I am using regex to search for the words to be replaced.

I'm writing this script in Python.

Edit: I will be searching the original text for words from a list, not literal words.  It is also important to match 'whole words'.

Comment: Are you having difficulty with the regex or just getting started?

Comment: *"I am using regex to search for the words to be replaced"* That seems to say you have something already, could you share it?

Comment: Could there be escaped quotes, and are you only worried about double quotes?

Comment: I don't have an issue with regex for searching what words I want to replace.  

I don't know how to replace some instances from others.

Comment: @sweeneyrod Only worried about double quotes

Comment: @wnnaw I could but I left the code at school...

Comment: Its always good to post how far you have gotten; especially as it seems you have the difficult part done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(\bmy\b)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sY8zY1/2)

Python demo:

```
>>> txt='''\
... Hello my name is "Tom, and my favourite sport is football" my O my
... Hello Tom, my name is Bonney
... not mymymy'''
>>> tgt='my'
>>> print re.sub(r'(\b%s\b)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)' % tgt, tgt.upper(), txt)
Hello MY name is "Tom, and my favourite sport is football" MY O MY
Hello Tom, MY name is Bonney
not mymymy
```

Comment: This caused an error in the demo, and still matched strings inside quotes

Comment: What error in which demo?